# NSScreen not updating monitor count when new monitors are plugged in

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode, macos, retina-display

I am finding that NSScreen is returning the same number of monitors even after additional monitors are plugged in.

Made a simple test app that can replicate the issue. Basically infinite loops and prints NSScreen counts and CGDisplay counts.

1. Start the app
2. printing “NSScreen = 1 CGDisplay = 1”
3. Without stopping the app, plug in an additional monitor
4. printing “NSScreen = 1 CGDisplay = 2”

However the code should be printing “NSScreen = 2 CGDisplay = 2”

On OS X 11, we see the same issue (NSScreen = 1 CGDisplay = 2) after plugging in the additional monitor.

Test Code is here:

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "macScreen.h"
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
  getNSScreenCoordinates();
  return 0;
}
```

macScreen.h

```
#ifndef macScreen_h
#define macScreen_h
float getNSScreenCoordinates();
#endif /* macScreen_h */
```

macScreen.mm

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <AppKit/NSScreen.h>
#define MAX_NUM_DISPLAYS 255
float getNSScreenCoordinates() {

  NSArray<NSScreen *> *arr = [NSScreen screens];
  NSUInteger numScreens = [arr count];

  CGDirectDisplayID displays[MAX_NUM_DISPLAYS];
  CGDisplayCount displayCount;
  CGGetOnlineDisplayList(MAX_NUM_DISPLAYS, displays, &displayCount);
  
  while(1) {
    std::cout << "cg num displays " << displayCount << "\n";
    std::cout << "numscreens " << numScreens << "\n";

    arr = [NSScreen screens];
    numScreens = [arr count];

    CGGetOnlineDisplayList(MAX_NUM_DISPLAYS, displays, &displayCount);
    
  }
  return 1;
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Any hints in the documentation of `NSScreen`?

Comment: The question is "why does nsscreen tell me there is only 1 monitor when there are 2?"

Answer (score 2):

In my testing on macOS 11.6 (Big Sur), you need to do two things to get `[NSScreen screens]` to update:

- You need to ensure the singleton `NSApplication.shared` object exists.
- You need to run the main `NSRunLoop`.

Here's an example (in Swift) that works:

```swift
import Cocoa
import Combine

// Ensure the singleton NSApplication exists.
_ = NSApplication.shared

// Arrange to print the number of screens once per second,
// while the main RunLoop is running.
let ticket = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common)
    .autoconnect()
    .sink { _ in
        print("screen count = \(NSScreen.screens.count)")
    }

// Run the main RunLoop forever.
RunLoop.main.run()

// Ensure that the Timer isn't cancelled prematurely.
ticket.cancel()
```

But if you comment out the `NSApplication.shared` line, it no longer works. If you replace the use of the `RunLoop` with a `while` loop that never invokes the `RunLoop`, it also no longer works. For example, the following does **not** work:

```swift
import Cocoa
import Combine

// Ensure the singleton NSApplication exists.
_ = NSApplication.shared

while true {
    // NEVER UPDATES
    print("screen count = \(NSScreen.screens.count)")
    sleep(1)
}
```

So you should really try to arrange your program so that `RunLoop.main` is in control. But if you really need to have your own main loop, it suffices to run one pass through `RunLoop.main` before checking `NSScreen.screens`. This version works:

```swift
import Cocoa
import Combine

// Ensure the singleton NSApplication exists.
_ = NSApplication.shared

while true {
    RunLoop.main.acceptInput(forMode: .default, before: .distantPast)
    print("screen count = \(NSScreen.screens.count)")
    sleep(1)
}
```

Comment: what about objective c?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs of [NSScreen](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsscreen?language=objc), you need to run your code within an NSApplication instance, to allow NSScreen to connect to the underlaying Display services. Do your work within `- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification`  suffice or call [NSApplicationLoad](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/1428475-nsapplicationload) before doing anything that requires a *DisplayServer* connection.

The fact that `NSScreen` is provided by `AppKit` indicates such requirements also.

You may consider register to the notification [NSApplicationDidChangeScreenParametersNotification](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplicationdidchangescreenparametersnotification?language=objc) or specify a  [CGDisplayRegisterReconfigurationCallback](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1455336-cgdisplayregisterreconfiguration?language=objc) function.